# Add div onclick using React, Gatsby, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Hello I am trying to add another container div on click. With my current code I am getting the error `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`. I got this answer from a stackoverflow problem and I beleive it does not work because I am using react/gatsby.

I have also tried having the `<button id="click"></button>` inside of trello.js and I am still getting the same error.

Trello.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./style.css"
import Button from "./Button"

export default function Trello() {


const draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable')
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container')

draggables.forEach(draggable => {
    draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
        draggable.classList.add('dragging')
    })

    draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
        draggable.classList.remove('dragging')
    })
})

containers.forEach(container => {
    container.addEventListener('dragover', () => {
        const draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging')
        container.appendChild(draggable)
    })
})


    return (
        <div>
            <Button />
        <div id="main-div">
            <div>
                    <div class="draggable"  draggable="true">Jason</div>
                    <div class="draggable"  draggable="true">Jack</div>
                    <div class="draggable"  draggable="true">Caleb</div>
                    <div class="draggable"  draggable="true">Ransom</div>
            </div>
            <body>
                <div class="container">
                        <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                        <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                        <p></p>
                </div>
            </body>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Button.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Button() {
    document.getElementById('click').onclick = function () {
        var div = document.createElement('div')
        div.className = 'container'
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button id="click"></button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `document` (to get the identifier) on processing render time where it isn't defined yet, as [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/) explains:

> Some of your code references “browser globals” like `window` or
>   `document`. If this is your problem you should see an error above like
>   “window is not defined”.

That's the reason why it is `null` in your snippet. If you want to do this, you may need to use a `useEffect`/`componentDidMount` hook/lifecycle. Both methods await and trigger once the component output has been rendered to the DOM.

However, accessing directly to the DOM in React is strongly not recommended, indeed, that's why you are using React, to create and manipulate a virtual DOM, where the cost (in terms of efficiency) for the browser to render and rerender it, instead of changing itself is the great value of React. Of course, it is not prohibited but you should avoid it. Instead, you can use `useRef` [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).

The last thing is that you may want to use something like this to achieve your goal is something like this:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Button() {
const createDiv =()=> <div className={`container`}>'Im a new div</div>

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={createDiv}>Click me</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The snippet above will create a new `<div>`, with "I'm a new div" inside as a return of your `onClick` function. If you need to create a new `<div>`on every click, the snippet needs a few changes, let me know and I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

export default function Button() {
  let click = () => {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "New DIV";
    div.className = "container";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={click}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```